# what is an event index in a tensorflow distribution

Tags: events, tensorflow

The tensorflow distribution has a method batch_shape which returns Shape of a single sample from a single event index as a TensorShape. Can someone shed some lights what is an event index?

Answer (score 1):

There are several concepts here, two of which are batch_shape and event_shape.

event_shape relates to the shape of your sample. For instance, scalar distributions like Normal, Poisson, Gamma have an event_shape of [] (this means that a single draw is scalar).

Multivariate distributions like a Bivariate normal distribution, can have a different event_shape (in this case [2], to represent that the draw is a 2 dimensional vector).

batch_shape refers to having a batch of distributions!

E.g. Normal(loc=[0., 0], scale=[2., 3]) has batch shape [2]. This is because it encodes that there are really 2 normal distributions: one with loc=0,scale=2. and another one with loc=0.,scale=3. It's just that we can carry around only one Normal object around, instead of 2 (and also all calculations will be batched, which can be good for speed).

For more information, I highly recommend looking at the notebook: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Understanding_TensorFlow_Distributions_Shapes.ipynb

Comment: Thanks. Still how does the concept of an index come in? How are the events indexed?

Comment: I think the comment "event index" is somewhat nebulous in that docstring (thanks for pointing that out, and I'll try to send a PR to fix it). It is supposed to mean for a single event (e.g. event shape of a Poisson is scalar, for MVN it is vector, etc.).